# Оптимизация выполнения SQL запроса Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация

помогите придумать решение.
Есть приобретенная система, работающая с БД Oracle 11g, со временем система стала работать значительно медленнее. При анализе проблемы выяснилось, что она генерирует запросы с неоптимальным планом выполнения, как пример:

```
select a,b,c from tab1 where a <> :1
```

При применении знака неравенства в условии, Oracle не использует индексы для поиска. Изменить запрос в программе нет возможности.

Как можно оптимизировать выполнение запроса в такой ситуации, или изменить запрос перед выполнением?

Comment: *При применении знака неравенства в условии, Oracle не использует индексы для поиска.* При принятии решения сервер ориентируется вовсе даже не на использованный оператор сравнения. А если условие недостаточно избирательно, то в этом запросе оптимизировать просто нечего...

Comment: В качестве бреда - а какой будет план для `select a,b,c from tab1 where a < :1 UNION ALL select a,b,c from tab1 where a > :1` ?

Comment: Oracle не рекомендует использовать оператор <> в запросах, т.к  поле "а" проиндексировано, но если смотреть план выполнения запроса, то получаем TABLE ACCESS FULL.

Comment: *Oracle не рекомендует использовать знак <> в запросах* Ну скорее потому, что "дай мне всё, кроме вот этого" чаще является логической ошибкой, чем правильно выраженным намерением... а так - оператор ничем не хуже прочих. Ну или попробуй использовать EXCEPT. Впрочем, от фуллскана не убежишь - не при выборке, так при отправке данных на клента.